# JavaFX webview html video playback not working in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, webview

I am completely new to JavaFX. I want to play a local video. I used webview and loaded the corresponding html file. **It worked fine on Windows 10 [java 9.0.1] but the same code is not working on Ubuntu [java 8u72]**. Is that because of the java version?

Below is the java code which I used:

```
private void loadJavaFXScene() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

            JFXPanel javafxPanel;
            javafxPanel = new JFXPanel();

            WebView webComponent = new WebView();
            webComponent.getEngine().load("file:///home/ubuntuuser/a.html");
            borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);

            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 250, 250);
            javafxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }  
    }
}
```

Below is the html code:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body>
```

Any help would be really useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say it is not working do you mean it doesn't play? Do you get an error? What happens exactly?

Comment: I was able to play this html file in browser.But when I loaded this in JavaFX webview,I am unable to play this file in Ubuntu.I just see a blank window.But with these codes,I am able to play the video in JavaFX webview in windows OS.

Comment: Perhaps try changing `file:///` to `file://`

Comment: No change.Before I got a white screen with a play button.Now after changing to file:// ,I get a white screen without a play button.

Comment: same problem but on windows. did you solved?